# Subdivide itertools.permutations process in Python

Tags: python, memory-management, python-itertools

Is there any way to subdivide a process that takes a lot of memory (itertools.permutations in this case) in order to improve the efficiency and to not run out of memory?

Comment: Why are you storing all of the permutations at once?

Comment: @Blender To convert them into a list (python list) and then compare it with another one.

Comment: You don't need to do that: just do `all(a == b for a, b in zip(other_one, permutations(...))) ` and you have a lazy equality check that only uses memory for one element at a time. (well, almost, since it checks for a *prefix* and not really for equality. But you can fix that using `zip_longest`).

Comment: @user3797646: What do you mean by "compare"? Can you explain exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Blender: Here's a post explaining what I'm trying to do (have a look at possible_existing_words() function): https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54957/permutations-program-in-python

Comment: @user3797646: Is having duplicates in the output a problem? If not, your only bound is the size of your dictionary.

Comment: @Blender: Actually the dictionary is just about 1 Mb, but the permutations one can be up to 4Gb (and more)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've backed yourself into a corner with `itertools.permutations`. Do you *really* need to check all of the possible permutations? Your dictionary is pretty small, so just iterate over the dictionary itself and validate each word:

```
import itertools
from collections import Counter

with open('/usr/share/dict/american-english', 'r') as handle:
    dictionary = frozenset(line.strip() for line in handle)

def existing_words(letters, length):
    letters_counter = Counter(letters)
    letters_set = frozenset(letters)

    for word in dictionary:
        if len(word) != length:
            continue

        if set(word) <= letters_set and Counter(word) <= letters_counter:
            yield word

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for word in existing_words('abcdefghijklmnopqrst', 5):
        print word
```